# I'm getting error in Pop3 ::open command using Tcl

Tags: tcl, pop3

I want to fetch email by `pop3` packages using `Tcl` from Pop3 server.

I proceed in this way

```
# Check Mail - a pop3 client

package require pop3

proc checkmail { _theHost  _theUser  _thePassword } {
     set h [pop3::open -socketcmd tls::socket \
     $_theHost $_theUser $_thePassword 995]
}

set _theHost "pop.gmail.com"
set _theUser "myusername"     #My email is myusername@gmail.com       
set _thePassword "mypassword"

checkmail $_theHost $_theUser $_thePassword
```

When I run `tclsh tclfile` it shows

```
invalid command name "tls::socket"
    while executing
"tls::socket pop.gmail.com 995"
    ("eval" body line emphasized text1)
    invoked from within
"eval [linsert $cstate(socketcmd) end $host $port]"
    (procedure "pop3::open" line 74)
    invoked from within
"pop3::open -socketcmd tls::socket  $_theHost $_theUser $_thePassword 995"
    (procedure "checkmail" line 3)
    invoked from within
"checkmail $_theHost $_theUser $_thePassword"
    (file "connection.txt" line 20)
```

Comment: Import the `tls` package as well and see if you still get the error?

Comment: yes I got connected  .. thank u @Jerry

Comment: i just installed tcltls package and it worked

Comment: @DebanjanaSarkar, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and accept Donal's answer if it solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

The `pop3` package doesn't include the support for encrypted connections by default; it knows how to use it (i.e., it can call `tls::socket` correctly) but since that's implemented by a binary package and you *might* be talking to an unencrypted system, it's only a soft dependency.

Fix it by adding:

```
package require tls
```

before the `package require pop3`. And adding the `tls` package to your system, if it isn't already there.

Answer (score 0):

In may 2016, Gmail POP3-emulated server no longer worked using POP3 (from tcllib) / tls packages.

The problem seems to be at openssl / tls versions level: openssl v1.0.1k, tcllib v1.15, tls v1.6, tcl v8.6.

TLSv1 option defaults to false, you've got to enable its use

```
package require tls
tls::init -ssl3 1 -tls1 1
```